# Create bootable Ubuntu ISO from bootable USB?

Tags: usb, virtualbox

I'm looking for help. Basically I have a bootable USB drive that has Ubuntu in it.

The USB stick looks like this:

[USB folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7k5gs.png)

I want to create a bootable ISO file from this USB, so that I can boot from it using VirtualBox, as apparently VB can't boot from USB.

I've searched online and most posts suggested ImgBurn, with the "Create image file from files/folders.

Apparently I need to select the "Make Image Bootable" option, however I'm not really sure how to configure the rest. I've tried a few different options but all have failed to boot using VirtualBox.

[ImgBurn bootable disc options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSQOb.png)

Does anyone have any ideas how to go about doing this? Tyvm in advance.

Comment: How was the bootable USB stick with Ubuntu created? Does it contain a standard system or some kind of customized system? - If this is the first time you try Ubuntu, I suggest that you download an Ubuntu iso file from the [official website](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) (and use the checksum to verify that the downloaded file is correct). It is free, you need *not* pay anything.

Comment: It was customized and (I assume) created using Cubic.

Comment: I see. Then you should use a cloning tool, to clone 'the whole drive' to an image (iso file). It might work with ImgBurn, but I have not used it. I have used [Win32DiskImager](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb), and there is a cloning option, ['DD-mode' in Rufus](https://rufus.ie). - In Ubuntu there are many options, please tell me if you have an Ubuntu (or other Linux) operating system running.

Comment: Used Rufus' option called "Create a disk image of the selected device" to create a VHD and managed to boot using Virtual Box. Thank you!

Comment: In Ubuntu you can use Gnome-Disks to create an image file, (.img), from the USB. Then you can use `VBoxManage clonemedium --format RAW ubuntu.img ubuntu.vdi` to change the image file to VDI so VBox can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use ISO image creator tool to make ISO image of USB drive. I have personally used Power ISO and Ultra ISO in Windows. But I never did this in Linux so I can't suggest you specific program but you can try alternatives of Power ISO for Linux:
https://alternativeto.net/software/power-iso/?platform=linux

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at the image of the folders in the bootable USB. I am not sure whether the USB is "live" -- whether it can be used to install its contents onto a drive. If so, that may open up [a variety of methods](https://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/2021/08/17/linux-v2p/) for imaging or ISOing those contents.

Possibly you can install Systemback on the running system, after booting the USB drive, and use Systemback to create an ISO. Alternately, it's not recommended to try to image a system while that system is running, but [possibly *dd* would succeed](https://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/2021/08/18/vmware-v2p/#Command) with a system that has been adequately stilled.

Have you explored booting a VM from the USB drive? I recently used Lubuntu to run commands inside an Ubuntu VM. Possibly some aspects of [that project](https://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/2021/08/18/vmware-v2p/#Prep) will be useful.

Other than that, I think PowerISO offers [a free version](https://www.poweriso.com/download-poweriso-for-linux.htm) for Linux. Hopefully that version offers this ability, perhaps using [the same steps](https://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/make-bootable-cd.htm) as its Windows version. There is also [TeraByte](https://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/2021/08/17/linux-v2p/).